# Apache Storm, co-partitioning of streams

Tags: apache-storm, partitioning

I have the following situation where I need to join two streams Bid(Seller, Item, Price) and Ask(Buyer, Item, Price) where I need to emit a tuple (Seller, Buyer) when the buyer offers a higher price than requested by the seller.

I know that I can configure the Bolt's grouping option FieldGrouping. But if I configure each input separately, is there a guarantee that the data with the same value will always go to the same Bolt task.

I am putting a pseudo code to help explain more

```
builder.setBolt("goodPrice", new GoodPriceBolt(), 5)
        .fieldsGrouping("Bid", new Fields("Item"))
        .FieldsGrouping("Ask", new Fields("Item"));
```

Now, as per the documentation http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Concepts.html, we can guarantee that all Bid data points for the same item value will be delivered to the same task. But, I am not sure if the code above will guarantee also that all Ask data points with the same item value as that of the Bid will be delivered to the same task.

In other words, I need to partition on Bid.Item = Ask.Item. Is that possible in Storm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I know. Joins is listed on Storm's page as a common pattern http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Common-patterns.html.

Here's the implementation of fields grouping in Storm https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/09e01231cc427004bab475c9c70f21fa79cfedef/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/daemon/GrouperFactory.java#L160. The values list contains the values of the fields you've specified in the field grouping (in your case "Item"). The id of the task to send the tuple to is based on https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/09e01231cc427004bab475c9c70f21fa79cfedef/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/utils/TupleUtils.java#L44, which uses the hash code of the values. As long as whatever is in your "Item" field implements hashCode properly, you should be good.

You might also be interested in http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.1/Joins.html, and maybe https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/SingleJoinExample.java. Keep in mind that when you join streams, you should try to take into account that the matching tuples might not show up in the joiner at the same time, which is why Storm provides a join bolt that lets you specify a window for how long you want to wait on one part of the match.